# improve update in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

Some times I need to generate to many insert querys, like this:

```
update claim set register_dt = '2014-01-29 09:48' where folio = '0021'
update claim set register_dt = '2014-04-09 11:30' where folio = '0080'
update claim set register_dt = '2014-05-06 13:00' where folio = '0123'
update claim set register_dt = '2014-05-21 12:20' where folio = '0161'
update claim set register_dt = '2014-01-03 10:40' where folio = '0001'
update claim set register_dt = '2014-01-06 09:12' where folio = '0002'
update claim set register_dt = '2014-01-06 10:40' where folio = '0003'
update claim set register_dt = '2014-01-07 13:00' where folio = '0004'
update claim set register_dt = '2014-01-08 11:50' where folio = '0005'
update claim set register_dt = '2014-01-10 12:34' where folio = '0006'
update claim set register_dt = '2014-01-13 09:45' where folio = '0007'
update claim set register_dt = '2014-01-15 09:29' where folio = '0008'
update claim set register_dt = '2014-01-15 10:05' where folio = '0009'
[... more and more]
```

And I get this text and execute one by one inside of some small script in php or visual studio.

I want to now if can **do this in some only unique query**, for update all in the mysql-browser client. (and not have to make an executor of querys every time) Tanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd choose to use a temporary table like @GordonLinoff shows. But that technically isn't a single query, because you have to create and populate the temporary table.

One way you can truly do this in a single query is to use a huge CASE expression:

```
update claim set register_dt = case folio
when '0021' then '2014-01-29 09:48'
when '0080' then '2014-04-09 11:30'
when '0123' then '2014-05-06 13:00' 
when '0161' then '2014-05-21 12:20'
when '0001' then '2014-01-03 10:40'
when '0002' then '2014-01-06 09:12'
when '0003' then '2014-01-06 10:40'
when '0004' then '2014-01-07 13:00'
when '0005' then '2014-01-08 11:50'
when '0006' then '2014-01-10 12:34'
when '0007' then '2014-01-13 09:45'
when '0008' then '2014-01-15 09:29' 
when '0009' then '2014-01-15 10:05'
. . . 
end;
```

You can make an SQL statement as long as `max_allowed_packet`.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way, in my opinion, would be a two step process.  First store the data in a temporary table and then use that for the update.

```
create temporary table toupdate as
    select '2014-01-29 09:48' as register_date, '0021' as folio union all
    . . .
    ;

update claim c join
       toupdate tu
       on c.folio = tu.folio
    set c.register_date = tu.register_date;
```

You can actually do this in one query if you like:

```
update claim c join
       (select '2014-01-29 09:48' as register_date, '0021' as folio union all
        . . .
       ) tu
       on c.folio = tu.folio
    set c.register_date = tu.register_date;
```

And, if the new values are in the database, you could just reference another source table where they are coming from.

Comment: Thanks, but looking for an answer like @Bill. To do what you say would have to do the inserts also, create and delete table (more work).

Comment: And the sorce of data is from other program or other source like CSV file from exel. The data is not in database. (the real problem is how to pass all data from outsite of db). I think perhaps I did not express well the question. thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Another tip is to avoid adding indexes to that table as much as possible because it slows down the speed of writing queries such as 'insert', 'delete' and 'update'